# How to make the size of the node bigger?

Tags: nodes

How do I make the size of the node larger?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [left,ultra thick] at (0,6) {$V_i$};
\node [left,ultra thick] at (0,3) {$V_f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @Sebastiano please don't.  It's ok for me don't worry!

Answer (score 2):

Using: `minimum size=4cm` you can increase the size of the node:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [left,minimum size=4cm] at (0,6) {$V_i$};
\node [left,minimum size=4cm] at (0,3) {$V_f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If the question is increase the size of the character, then you can add `\large`, `\Huge`, etc., as from this code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [left,minimum size=4cm] at (0,6) {\large{$V_i$}};
\node [left,minimum size=4cm] at (0,3) {\Huge{$V_f$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is not doing the magic for me.

Comment: minimum size option is making the box bigger in which the name of node resides.

Comment: I edited your answer.

Comment: Maybe add `scale=2,transform shape` instead of `minimum size=4cm`?

Comment: @marmot Of course, but from my humble point of view the question is not clear and not even complete from the point of view of the MWE. Thank you very much for your intervention and I appreciate you very much.